# Intellij idea 2020.2 - JSF tool window not showing

Tags: intellij-idea

I cannot find the JSF tool window as described in the following link:

[JSF tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/jsf-tool-window.html?fbclid=IwAR2dG_xq8p_lNvINZ5n7YxxhyUn2_klDMOOCu_2PnRa4rg1Jmp5paz40Fv4)

I am using the following version:

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-202.6948.69, built on August 25, 2020

Also, made sure that the **Java EE: Java Server Faces plugin** is enabled.

Do I miss any step to prepare my project for JSF? Or the Intellij-idea documentation is outdated?